# How important is it to upgrade to Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have a computer that meets the minimum system requirements and more including a TPM2 .

I want to know if it is necessary to upgrade to Windows 11 or if it is just an option. Will applications drop support, will  I lose features, etc.?

Comment: How important is it to pound nails into your skull?  Win11 has several degradations and nothing other than eye-candy as "upgrades"

Comment: "Will applications drop support" - this is pretty much inevitable with any new versions of OS's, although it typically does take a while (most applications even still support Windows 7 or Vista). "Will I lose features" - what, you mean in the OS itself? No, they won't start stripping existing features out of an existing OS (except for online things, like updates, but this typically has a clear end-of-support date).

Comment: The TV commercials imply that downloading or playing games is much faster with less buffering in Windows 11...can that be possible?  I doubt Microsoft would make a blatant lie, so is there some improved hardware optimization?

Comment: @bobuhito If they made significant changes to the VFS layer (like, for example, not blatantly hooking the integrated AV software into _every single VFS call_ as seems to be the case in W10) or the networking stack it actually is possible. Of course, it’s not really that much of a practical benefit given that many big-name games have actual issues at runtime on W11 (either performance problems compared to W10, or actual stability issues).

Comment: I'm still using Windows 7 and MacOS Sierra... w/o any troubles (unlike some my friends with Windows 10). so... In my experience, in general, it's important to wait at least a few months/a year before upgrading to a new software version.

Comment: Seems like a poor question since there will be a different answer one month from now, one year from now, etc.

Comment: VTC as opinion based. This question boils down to a software rec question but for Windows 11 (and other alternative OSes).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not at all, at the moment. To be honest, I wouldn't recommend upgrading until Windows 11 has been tested by more people. At some point in the future you will be forced to if you want to use an application that requires Windows 11 and will not run on 10. But that day is a long time away. Microsoft is pretty good with backwards compatibility (even though that has many downsides).

I haven't found any must-have features in Windows 11 so far.

In October 2025 Microsoft will stop supporting Windows 10 though so you should switch before then.

Comment: This is not an answer, just an opinion.

Comment: @Moab the first sentence is a claim of fact, to which most of us agree.

Comment: @Moab The question is seeking opinion—expert, educated opinion, backed up with reasoning and facts. That’s what this answer is—opinion that *is* an answer. The two are not mutually exclusive. Indeed, there is no “factual” answer to this question: upgrading has pros and cons and deciding where the balance lies is always going to be a matter of some opinion. Right now, though, it’s so lop-sided that it’s hard to imagine anyone suggesting that it is “important” for users to upgrade at this time.

Comment: @KRyan: The Micro$oft marketers will suggest that.

Comment: @user21820 At this moment? Microsoft is pushing me to be “ready” for the upgrade, but they’re not suggesting I actually _do it_. The machine that is “11 ready” doesn’t mention it, the older machine that isn’t has a note that it isn't, but that’s all I get. Their marketing right now is much more “get excited for this thing that’s coming” than it is “get it now.” At some point, yes, of course they’ll suggest it—but at that point, the balance will have shifted. Eventually, it will (likely, barring another ME or Vista) shift so much that it’ll be lopsided in the other direction.

Comment: @KRyan: Hah. Have you forgotten the [insidious silent upgrades from the past](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2015/11/10/microsoft-admits-windows-10-automatic-installs)? =P

Comment: Questions seeking opinions are off topic here, you should vote to close rather than answer.

Comment: @Moab I'd argue this isn't even opinion based. The question asks "how important" - not "should one upgrade". By any definition of the word "important" it is not currently important for any user to upgrade. The statement "Not at all, at the moment" is a direct, factual answer. There is one opinion provided as to *why* it is unimportant, and while there are certainly others, I can't imagine a valid reason as to why it is, in fact, important to upgrade to Windows 11 today.

Comment: "Will applications drop support" can be answered with the fact that they will, but that that day is a long time away. I am here to (try to) be helpful to people. If the rules would get in the way of that I would ignore them. But in this case I'd argue they didn't.

Comment: The only thing I might suggest adding to this answer is around paid vs free upgrades - it's worth upgrading to Windows 11 at some stage while it's still free, if you wait too long it is currently planned to become a paid upgrade. Definitely agree not much point right now.

Comment: @Moab Please see [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more information on "subjective topics"

Comment: @Moab Unless you are asking for the solution to a mathematical theorem, to which there is only one possible answer, *everything* is an opinion. SE exists to share answers which are objective, informed opinions backed by evidence, experience and expertise. This is one of those.

Comment: I dont make the rules here.

Comment: @Moab SE is absolutely welcoming to a variety of subjective questions where the answer may be opinion based. have a look at [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Furthermore, it is clearly outlined in [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) that there are acceptable subjective questions. Furthermore, this question expands on asking for a subjective opinion "should I switch" by asking about specific feature / application support.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question depends on a lot of different factors.

In an organization with a large fleet of computers and a lots of specific applications that has to continue to function is one situation that is quite different from if you are a home user with one or a few computers.

Regardless, any upgrade of the operating system to W11 will have some upsides and some downsides as well as a number of risks. As there is no real hurry to upgrade for most of us, it might be a good idea to let other people find and mitigate the problems. Programs might stop working, configurations may change, maybe some or other of your hardware will not be supported.

So wait until is my suggestion. But until depends. When new versions of the programs you use will require W11, or perhaps the W11 has functions you really appreciate.

My guess is that you could probably run your current setup until the computer dies, many years from now. It is not like staying on W10 makes your computers worse of time, it will stay the same. Except for one factor: security. One risk you will take is that security updates will no longer be available, but according to MS that is sometime into 2025 for W10, so no hurry there.

Comment: 2015 was 6 years ago.

Comment: I don't think that the answer to the question would be different for a home user than for an organization with many computers. In both cases I would not recommend upgrading to Windows 11 (at this specific moment in time).